# How to write bson format of mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

Am able to update an array object in a mongodb document using the command line query

```
db.slicecoll.updateOne({"_id": "3ca85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66af33","allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList._id": "3"},
{
  "$set": {
    "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].allowedSnssai.sst": 2,
    "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].allowedSnssai.sd": "4",
    "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].tac": "3021",
    "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].zone": "zone1",
    "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].IMSI": "2443800000033"
  }
},
  {
    "arrayFilters": [{ "inner._id": "3" }]
  })
```

however, writing the bson.M form of the above query has been difficult, i have tried

```
ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
selector := bson.M{"_id": "3ca85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66af33", "allowedNssaiList.allowedSnssaiList._id": "3"}

UpdateArray := bson.M{"$set": bson.M{
        "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].allowedSnssai.sst": 2,
        "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].allowedSnssai.sd":  "4",
        "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].tac":               "3021",
        "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].zone":              "zone1",
        "allowedNssaiList.$.allowedSnssaiList.$[inner].IMSI":              "2443800000033"}}

arrayFilter := bson.M{ "arrayFilters": [{ "inner._id": "3" }]}

opts := options.Update().SetUpsert(true)
_, err := db.Collection(COLLECTION).UpdateOne(ctx, selector, UpdateArray, opts, options.ArrayFilters(arrayFilter))
```

but am having syntax error about the arrayFilter varaible. 
Any help to find out what am doing wrong?

I have change the filter setting to

```
_, err := db.Collection(COLLECTION).UpdateOne(ctx, selector, UpdateArray, opts,options.UpdateOptions().SetArrayFilters(options.ArrayFilters{Filters: []interface{}{bson.M{"inner._id": "3"}}}))
```

but i was getting error message "missing argument to conversion to options.UpdateOptions: options.UpdateOtions()".

Comment: `[{ ... }]` is not a thing in Go. If you want to set `"arrayFilters"` to a list of objects, maybe try using `bson.A`? Or `bson.D`?

Comment: I have change it to                                                                                                     _, err := db.Collection(COLLECTION).UpdateOne(ctx, selector, UpdateArray, opts, options.UpdateOptions().SetArrayFilters(options.ArrayFilters{Filters: []interface{}{bson.M{"inner._id": "3"}}}))     but i was getting "missing argument to conversion to options.UpdateOptions: options.UpdateOtions()"

Comment: [`UpdateOptions`](https://godoc.org/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo/options#UpdateOptions) is not a function but a struct type. You probably meant to write `options.Update().SetArrayFilters( ...`

Comment: It works after making the change.

Comment: It works using the options.Update().SetArrayFilters( ...

Comment: @tom, I would request you to please answer your own question, so others can benefit from it.